# Blender Object keeps moving back to 0,0,0

Tags: objects, transforms

I am new to blender, and I have just created a island using ANT landscapes, and I have build two boats for this.

[image: Two boats]

Two boats on island 
They are in this place when I am in object mode, but when I render it they appear here:

[image: Island with boats in wrong place]

I check the position of where they end up, and it is both where they were imported and 0,0,0. Although, all the other objects I have imported have not changed position. Does anyone know about how to fix this or have experienced this problem?

Comment: Have you tried applying the location of the boats? (Ctrl-A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the location of the objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, otherwise the location is reset when you render.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense to me. If he's created the boats, and he's placed them using normal grs operations, then applying the location shouldn't be necessary, AFAIK. Can you explain what's going on? Why does the location get reset when he renders?

Comment: @Matt, it could be a multitude of problems. There could be parented objects, there might be a constraint messing it up, they were imported, so the origin might be screwed up. Applying the location will solve the issue of an object's position resetting most of the time.

Comment: Yeah, that might make sense. I just feel like it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 20):

I think you've accidentally added a keyframe. You can confirm by moving the boat (with <kbd>G</kbd>) and then pressing the right arrow to scroll to a different frame. If the boat snaps back to where it was before you moved it, then it's been keyframed. **Applying the location will keep the boat from moving... but it won't solve the problem.** If you want to move it again, you'll have to apply the location again, and so on.

If the above reveals a rogue keyframe, open the graph editor and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete all the keyframes (assuming you aren't animating anything that you want to keep; otherwise, just delete the keyframes for the boat).

You can delete all the location keyframes for the boat by selecting it and then looking in *3D view > Properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D view) > Transform > Location*:

[image]

If the values are highlighted green, or yellow like in the above screenshot, that means they have a keyframe. (Yellow means there is a keyframe *on this frame*, green means there is a keyframe on *some other frame*).

To delete all location keyframes on that object, right click on one of the values and select *Clear Keyframes*:

[image]